# Using "Not in" in drools decision table

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

How to use "not in" for range of values in drools decision table?

Example,  I've a method called `HMT_HomeInfo.get("HM").Value` and values are

368.00-368.99, V72.0-V72.9, 369.00-369.99, 366-367.99, 7430-743.99.

Comment: **Your own questions (!)**   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492825/how-to-write-a-rule-for-alphanumeric-ranges-in-drools-using-excel-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993404/create-alias-for-conditions-in-drools-decision-table answer this sufficiently.  If not, provide sample code showing the problem that is not solved by these answers.

Comment: I marked that as an answer. Thank you for reminding :)

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use not in operator in decision tables?

Comment: Sure: it's the same as the operator `in` (which, forgive if I'm wrong) with which you seem to be familair and comfortable. However, for *ranges* you need to use operators  `<=`, `>=`, `<`, `>` in combination with `&&` to match values not between any of the range bounds.

Comment: So, will the syntax be HMT_HomeInfo.get("HM").Value not in (>= 368.00 && <= 368.99) ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993404/create-alias-for-conditions-in-drools-decision-table

Comment: Not sure why you'are pointing to that question. I need help with the syntax.

Comment: Are you a programmer? Its comparison operations (values combined with `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`) combined with logical operators to form a logical expression. As in the answer you accepted in that question...

Comment: I accepted krautmeyer answer. In that there is no syntax which combines not operator with range of values. Sorry, I couldn't get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by providing the range of values in CONDITION that I don't want to include and then include "False" below the range as shown in figure. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If `$v` is a variable bound to the value you need to test, then

```
! ("368.00" <= $v && $v <= "368.99" ||
   "V72.0"  <= $v && $v <= "V72.9" ||
   ...
   "743.00  <= $v && $v <= "743.99" )
```

is an expression that returns true if `$v` is not in one of these intervals.

Be advised that these comparisons use *string* comparison, which may or may not return what you expect when these strings contain what looks like a number.

Comment: It's throwing an error "mismatched input '!' in rule"

Comment: You may have put this in the wrong place in the rule.

Comment: $h: HMT_HomeInfo.get("HM").Value !( >= '36800' && <= '36899' ||  $h >= '36900' && <= '36999' || $h >= '366' && <= '36799' || $h >= '7430' && <= '74399') This is what I uesd

Comment: This is not a pattern according to Drools syntax. Section 7.8.3.2 in the Drools documentation explains this - it's way too long to put into a comment.